# A problem raised by Roth's theorem and the notion of approximation exponent

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

**Roth's theorem** states that every algebraic irrational has approximation exponent equal to $2$.  It follows from Theorem 1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406300 that the approximation exponent of an irrational real number $\alpha$ is equivalently the infimum of all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$q_{n+1}^{\log n/\log q_n} = O(n^{t-1}) \ (n \to \infty),$$
where $q_n$ is the denominator of the $n$th convergent $p_n/q_n$ of the simple continued fraction expansion of $\alpha$.  For some irrationals of approximation exponent $2$, it seems that
$$q_{n+1}^{\log n/\log q_n} \sim n \ (n \to \infty).$$
Indeed, this appears to be the case for $\alpha = e$ and $\alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  My question is, for which class or classes of irrationals $\alpha$ of approximation exponent $2$ does the asymptotic above hold?  And what is the Lebesgue measure of the set of all such $\alpha$ (if it exists)?

Note that $\alpha$ has approximation exponent $2$ if and only if $\log q_{n+1} \sim \log q_n$, if and only if $\log (q_{n+1}^{\log n/\log q_n}) \sim \log n$, if and only if $q_{n+1}^{\log n/\log q_n} = n^{1+o(1)}$.

N.B. One can also ask for which irrationals $\alpha$ of approximation exponent $2$ one has
$$q_{n+1}^{\log n/\log q_n} \sim Cn \ (n \to \infty)$$
for some $C >0$, or, instead,
$$q_{n+1}^{\log n/\log q_n} \asymp n \ (n \to \infty).$$
The problem also can be generalized to irrationals of approximation exponent $\mu < \infty$ by replacing $n$ with $n^{\mu-1}$.  But I'm happy to restrict the problem to the original question asked above.

Comment: This is equivalent to $\log q_{n+1} / \log q_n = 1 + o(\frac1{\log n})$

Comment: True!  Then the quantity being $\asymp n$ is equivalent to $\log q_{n+1}/\log q_n = 1 + O(1/\log n)$.

Comment: In fact, numerical evidence seems to suggest that, for almost all real numbers, one has $\log q_{n+1}/\log q_n = 1 +O(n^{-1+\varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ (or maybe with the quantifiers reversed)!  But I'm no expert in Diophantine approximation!

Comment: Or, less boldly, almost all real numbers satisfy $\log q_{n+1}/\log q_n = 1 +O(n^{-\varepsilon})$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: You can try to use [Lévy's Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LevyConstant.html) or [Lochs' Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LochsTheorem.html), perhaps together with [Khinchin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Khinchin's_theorem_on_metric_Diophantine_approximation_and_extensions)

Comment: Levy's constant is equivalent to $\log q_n \sim \frac{\pi^2}{12 \log 2} n$, and thus yields $\log q_{n+1} \sim \log q_n$ (but nothing more), for almost all real $\alpha$.  I don't think Loch's theorem applies, but what Khinchin's theorem or the Duffin-Schaeffer theorem might say I'm not sure yet.  (Koukoulopoulos and Maynard proved a stronger version of Khinchin's theorem in 2019.)